# Python regex, keep alphanumeric but remove numeric

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove numbers in my string but keep alphanumeric as is using regex in python.

```
" How to remove 123 but keep abc123 from this question?"
```

I want result to be like:

```
"How to remove but keep abc123 from this question?"
```

I tried

```
spen=re.sub('[0-9]+', '', que)
```

but it removes all numbers.
I want `abc123` to be as is.

Comment: How is that a duplicate of *Python regular expression match whole word* ? This is the same type of answer, but the questions have nothing to do with each other...

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [word boundary symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, something like this:

```
re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+\b', '', que)
```

That will not match numbers that are part of a longer word.

Comment: Great!! It worked. Thanks khelwood,